# How does taking the conj of a function change what would otherwise be a regular convolution? `ifft2( conj(fft2(f)) .* fft2(tmp)`

Tags: matlab, image-processing, floating-point, fft, convolution

I'd like to be able to convert some matlab code to C. I believe the following snippet creates a new image where each pixel is the sum of the local pixels in the in the source image in a h*w rectangle centered on the pixel, for odd h and w at least.

```
[rows, cols] = size(img);

tmp = ...
%Is mostly input img, but also extended on all sides by reflecting edge values.
%Extended above and below by h each, left and right by w each.

f = zeros(rows+2*h, cols+2*w);

f(1:h, 1:w) = 1;

sumimg = real( ifft2( conj(fft2(f)) .* fft2(tmp) ) );

%then cut out the center of the original input size.
```

I don't know much about the FFT, but I think I understand what a convolution is in image processing and that the FFT is one way to do it. I'm wondering what the `conj()` does, because I did not see it in the bit of reading on the convolution theorem I did.

My second question is: for floating point with `h=w=63`, how does the accuracy of the above compare to my C method, which is (ignoring edges):

Have an auxiliary array for the current sums of column segments.

Init: Sum the first h rows into the aux, while adding the last row output sums of completed rectangles.

Then the core for the rest of the rows is:

```
//top == bot-(h-1)*stride;
double partial = 0;
int j=0;
for ( ; j!=w-1; ++j)//presum first w-1 elems, and roll column sums
    partial += (aux[j] += bot[j] - top[j]);

for ( ; j!=segcols; ++j)
{
    double result = partial + (aux[j] += bot[j] - top[j]);
    output(result);
    partial = result - aux[j-(w-1)];
}
```

So all I'm doing is simple adds and subs, but I'm not sure if adding `h=63` elements sequentially to each column accumulator in the init step, and the following arithmetic is worse than the complex FFT math, regarding floating point precision.

Comment: The use of the conjugate in this case effectively reverses the filter, due to the way exponents in the Discrete Fourier Transform operate. It effectively makes the operation a convolution instead of a correlation.

Comment: FFTs generally have well-behaved error properties, typically O(n log n) compared to O(n^2) for direct computation of the DFT. Computing a filter by direct arithmetic is likely to have worse error than using an FFT unless the filter is small. You could explore by computing a reference result using `double` and using that to evaluate the error that occurs in computing using `float` with an FFT or with direct arithmetic.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Thanks for the feedback. I think you meant the other-way around of "It [taking the conjugate] effectively makes the operation a convolution instead of a correlation". Though if the filter is the same number for each entry (1's in this case), convolution and correlation should be the same, I think.